# How to solve an overdetermined nonlinear set of equations using Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation-solving, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-optimization

I have following Code in Matlab:

```
function y = myfun(x)

        % Set Variables
        Svl=1;
        B=54.433;
        F=4379.250;
        T=21.398;
        V=53363.500;

        % Computing Prefactors with set variables
        Zahl1=-B+13.2855-6.10101*Svl;
        Zahl2=-F-13938.9+5073.43*Svl;
        Zahl3=-V-599882+229920*Svl;
        Zahl4=-T-8.2379-0.964978*Svl;
        Pl1=2.99983 -0.438557 *Svl;
        Pl2=850.573-294663*Svl;
        Pl3=31769.1-12055.5*Svl;
        Pl4=1.80671 -0.256667 *Svl;
        vs1=0.0255558*Svl -0.0498925;
        vs2=20.0274 -8.33864*Svl;
        vs3=1061.95-415.967*Svl;
        vs4=-0.00980451+0.0119915*Svl;
        Plvs1=-0.00215169;
        Plvs2=-1.20681+0.465007*Svl;
        Plvs3=-56.1611+21.7506*Svl;
        Plvs4=-0.00162471;

        % Equations
        y = zeros(4,1);
        y(1) = Zahl1+Pl1*x(1)+vs1*x(2)+Plvs1*x(1)*x(2);
        y(2) = Zahl2+Pl2*x(1)+vs2*x(2)+Plvs2*x(1)*x(2);
        y(3) = Zahl3+Pl3*x(1)+vs3*x(2)+Plvs3*x(1)*x(2);
        y(4) = Zahl4+Pl4*x(1)+vs4*x(2)+Plvs4*x(1)*x(2);
```

I have a set of four nonlinear equations y() and only two unknowns x(1) and x(2). Zahlx, Plx, vsx and Plvsx are known and only prefactors which are computed before in this code.

**How do I solve the above set of overdetermined nonlinear equations in Matlab?**

I tried it with the least squeres:

```
x0 = [20,100];
lb = [20,100];
ub = [40,500];
[x,resnorm,res,eflag,output1] = lsqnonlin(@myfun,x0, lb, ub); % Invoke optimizer

x(1)
x(2)
```

But the result makes no sence.

I get the following result:

```
Initial point is a local minimum.

Optimization completed because the size of the gradient at the initial point 
is less than the default value of the function tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>
%x(1)
ans =
    20 
%x(2)
ans =
   100
```

But x(1) should be near 40 and x(2) near 500.
He computed only the start point.

Any ideas?

I hope somebody can help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: "But the result makes no sence" What are the results? what else have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, I edited the result or error.

Comment: Strictly speaking, one cannot "solve" an over-determined system. One can only find an "optimal solution", where the criteria can be LS, MLE, etc. I suggest you upload an image showing the equation system - this way it would be much easier to understand, instead of trying to infer it from your code.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. I finally got the rigth result. There was only a comma in my values missing.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. I got finally the right results. There was only a comma in my prefactors missing. If someone has the same problem, the code is working.